# VideoSurveilance Application whichs was provided by Emgucv bundle Hangs on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: .net, mono, monodevelop, emgucv, raspberry-pi2

When i try to run the VideoSurveilance Application on Raspberry Pi2.The Application hang's,I followed the steps From this Link[EmguCv Download and Installation Steps](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Raspbian_.28Raspberry_Pi_2.29)

are there any dll's i have been missing other example's are running fine.

Here is my code For blob tracking

```
using (CvTracks tracks = new CvTracks())
using (ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer())
using (Capture capture = new Capture())
using (Mat fgMask = new Mat())
 {
   //BGStatModel<Bgr> bgModel = new BGStatModel<Bgr>(capture.QueryFrame(), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BG_STAT_TYPE.GAUSSIAN_BG_MODEL);
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgModel = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(0, 0, true);
   //BackgroundSubstractorMOG bgModel = new BackgroundSubstractorMOG(0, 0, 0, 0);

    capture.ImageGrabbed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       Mat frame = new Mat();
       capture.Retrieve(frame);
        bgModel.Apply(frame, fgMask);

         using (CvBlobDetector detector = new CvBlobDetector())
         using (CvBlobs blobs = new CvBlobs())
          {
              detector.Detect(fgMask.ToImage<Gray, Byte>(), blobs);
              blobs.FilterByArea(100, int.MaxValue);

              tracks.Update(blobs, 20.0, 10, 0);

              Image<Bgr, Byte> result = new Image<Bgr, byte>(frame.Size);

               using (Image<Gray, Byte> blobMask = detector.DrawBlobsMask(blobs))
                {
                  frame.CopyTo(result, blobMask);
                }
                //CvInvoke.cvCopy(frame, result, blobMask);

                foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, CvTrack> pair in tracks)
                 {
                   if (pair.Value.Inactive == 0) //only draw the active tracks.
                   {
                     CvBlob b = blobs[pair.Value.BlobLabel];
                     Bgr color = detector.MeanColor(b, frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>());
                      result.Draw(pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value.BoundingBox.Location, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace.HersheySimplex, 0.5, color);
                        result.Draw(pair.Value.BoundingBox, color, 2);
                        Point[] contour = b.GetContour();
                        result.Draw(contour, new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 1);
                      }
                }

             viewer.Image = frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ConcateVertical(fgMask.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ConcateHorizontal(result));
             }
         };
         capture.Start();
         viewer.ShowDialog();
     }
```

Comment: Add the exception details.

Comment: @gusman Iam not getting any exception it just launch the application and hangs there itself..:( :(

Comment: Does the whole device hang, or just your application? What if you try another PI device? Have you put any logging into your application to see where it is hanging? Does it get to capture.start()?

Comment: only the application hangs.yes i have put the log's. From log's i came to know till blob detection application was working fine but after the application gets hang.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the project, however reading your question and going over the notes of the link you provided and their [main/home page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page); they mention and keep referring to Raspberry Pi 2, whereas, you have only mentioned Raspberry Pi.

It's a subtle difference but could be a limitation in the ARM6 architecture, RAM, or other. If you're on a Pi2, then you may disregard, but if you're on anything pre Pi2, you may need to address other areas to make it compatible. That's if it's at all supported.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could cause a "hang" at that point is lack of free space on the card.

I would try this first: **`Expand root filesystem`**
http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions

To check how much space you have left:

```
df -h  /
```